# How does Direct2D do non-MSAA Anti-Aliasing?

Tags: directx, direct3d, direct2d

mrvux described how Direct2D works under the hood [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69911070/11998382):

> Please note that when tessellating bezier path D2D does a very great work at making the resulting geometry non self intersecting (so alpha blending works properly even on some complex self intersecting path).
>
> In case on rounded rectangle, it does the same, just tessellates into triangles.
>
> This allows it to minimize draw calls to a good extent, as well as allowing anti alias on a non msaa surface (**this is done at mesh level**, with some small triangles with alpha).

Can someone explain what "*this is done at mesh level*" means?

I am currently rendering my line strip's via `ID2D1PathGeometry`. However, the line strip data is on the gpu, and I now want to render them without reading back to the cpu (i.e. with the 3D pipeline). How can I do non-msaa anti-aliasing like Direct2D?

The only resource I could find was [Line Rasterization Rules (Antialiased, Without Multisampling)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d11/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-rasterizer-stage-rules#line-rasterization-rules-antialiased-without-multisampling). This type of rasterization is called [alpha line anti-aliasing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ns-d3d11-d3d11_rasterizer_desc).

Since `alpha line anti-aliasing` can only render line-strips with a width of `1`, I assume that Direct2D must tessellate the line into a triangle strip when the width is not equal to `1`. But what happens when the width is `1`? Would Direct2D use line-strips in this case? It's no clear how Direct2D can anti-alias a triangle strip without msaa.

**Edit**: I'm going to go ahead with `alpha line anti-aliasing` so this question is mostly to satisfy my curiosity.

**Edit 2**: `alpha line anti-aliasing` isn't actually doing any alpha blending on my hardware, it just draws an aliased line but thicker (which is good enough for me). This is also true of the results here https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Line-drawing-and-anti-aliasing#anti-aliased-lines

Comment: Keep in mind that most of Direct2D's processing is done on the CPU to generate Direct3D low-level line, pixel, and triangle primitives. As such, it uses classic CPU-based techniques for rasterization.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn so you're saying it draws the edges of filled shape pixel by pixel to achieve the anti-aliasing? Doing pixel by pixel calculations on the cpu?

Comment: I found an example of the result to expect from `alpha line anti-aliasing` https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Line-drawing-and-anti-aliasing#anti-aliased-lines